# Apache não está mais iniciando após ssl_module habilitado?

Tags: apache, ssl, wampserver

O Apache costumava funcionar normalmente. Porém, quando estava tentando configurar minha intranet para envio de emails, fui direcionada a habilitar o módulo ssl_module do Apache. Foi só clicar em cima que o Apache caiu e não voltou mais. Quando tento clicar novamente para desmarcar, obtenho esse erro:

[image: Módulo habilitado]
[image: Erro do Apache]

Já tentei iniciar pelo services.msc, mas sem sucesso. Não cheguei a alterar a página httpd.conf, por isso é irrelevante postar o código aqui, visto que estava funcionando antes com o mesmo código. Qual pode ser o problema?

Aliás, o problema não é outro app estar utilizando a mesma porta. Ao verificar a porta 80 utilizada pelo apache, percebe-se que a mesma não é utilizada por aplicativo nenhum:

[image: Porta 80]

Preciso consertar isso urgente!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou compartilhar uma solução que encontrei para o apache não iniciar após o `ssl_module` ser habilitado.

1. Verifique que o `ssl_module` está marcado como habilitado dentro das opções do
   *Apache* no *Wamp*.
2. Clique em `ssl_module` como se fosse desabilitar o mesmo.

   - A mensagem de erro abaixo deverá aparecer:
     [image: Mensagem de erro da configuração ssl_module do Apache]
3. Abra o arquivo `httpd.conf` pelas configurações do *Apache* no menu do
   *Wamp* ou pela pasta do *Apache* dentro do Disco Local.
4. Procure por essa linha dentro do arquivo: `LoadModule ssl_module
   modules/mod_ssl.so`.
5. Quando encontrar adicione um jogo da velha (#) no início da mesma,
   para que ela fique assim:

   - `#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`
6. Salve o arquivo e reinicie o *Wamp*.
7. Tente abrir seu projeto localhost e confirme que o *Wamp* está executando normalmente.

   > Observação: Pode ser que não funcione para todos os casos por alguma
   >   alteração que você possa haver feito anteriormente nos módulos.